# Test for equality among all elements of a single numeric vector

Tags: r, vector, equality

I'm trying to test whether all elements of a vector are equal to one another. The solutions I have come up with seem somewhat roundabout, both involving checking `length()`.

```
x <- c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 1)  # FALSE
y <- rep(2, times = 7)       # TRUE
```

With `unique()`:

```
length(unique(x)) == 1
length(unique(y)) == 1
```

With `rle()`:

```
length(rle(x)$values) == 1
length(rle(y)$values) == 1
```

A solution that would let me include a tolerance value for assessing 'equality' among elements would be ideal to avoid [FAQ 7.31](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/FAQ/R-FAQ.html#Why-doesn_0027t-R-think-these-numbers-are-equal_003f) issues.

Is there a built-in function for type of test that I have completely overlooked? `identical()` and `all.equal()` compare two R objects, so they won't work here.

**Edit 1**

Here are some benchmarking results. Using the code:

```
library(rbenchmark)

John <- function() all( abs(x - mean(x)) < .Machine$double.eps ^ 0.5 )
DWin <- function() {diff(range(x)) < .Machine$double.eps ^ 0.5}
zero_range <- function() {
  if (length(x) == 1) return(TRUE)
  x <- range(x) / mean(x)
  isTRUE(all.equal(x[1], x[2], tolerance = .Machine$double.eps ^ 0.5))
}

x <- runif(500000);

benchmark(John(), DWin(), zero_range(),
  columns=c("test", "replications", "elapsed", "relative"),
  order="relative", replications = 10000)
```

With the results:

```
          test replications elapsed relative
2       DWin()        10000 109.415 1.000000
3 zero_range()        10000 126.912 1.159914
1       John()        10000 208.463 1.905251
```

So it looks like `diff(range(x)) < .Machine$double.eps ^ 0.5` is fastest.

Comment: For equality without tolerance, `max(x) == min(x)` is an order of magnitude faster than `diff(range(x))`, and works with characters as well as numbers

Answer (score 41, accepted):

I use this method, which compares the min and the max, after dividing by the mean:

```
# Determine if range of vector is FP 0.
zero_range <- function(x, tol = .Machine$double.eps ^ 0.5) {
  if (length(x) == 1) return(TRUE)
  x <- range(x) / mean(x)
  isTRUE(all.equal(x[1], x[2], tolerance = tol))
}
```

If you were using this more seriously, you'd probably want to remove missing values before computing the range and mean.

Comment: I chose this one for being faster than Dirk's. I don't have millions of elements, but this should run a little quicker for me.

Comment: @Kevin: what about John's solution?  It's ~10x faster than Hadley's and allows you to set tolerance.  Is it deficient in some other way?

Comment: Please provide some benchmarking - I just checked mine is about the same for a vector of a million uniforms.

Comment: @hadley: I was running `system.time(for(i in 1:1e4) zero_range(x))`, where `x` was from the OP.  John's solution is ~10x for `x`, ~3x faster for `y` and slightly slower for `runif(1e6)`.

Comment: 10x difference doesn't matter much when you're looking at the difference between 0.00023 and 0.000023 seconds - and DWin would probably claim they are the same to the specified degree of tolerance ;)

Comment: Nice. What does ``isTRUE`` do that ``all.equal`` doesn't already do? Thanks.

Answer (score 76):

Why not simply using the variance:

```
var(x) == 0
```

If all the elements of `x` are equal, you will get a variance of `0`.
This works only for double and integers though.

**Edit based on the comments below:**
A more generic option would be to check for the length of unique elements in the vector which must be 1 in this case. This has the advantage that it works with all classes beyond just double and integer from which variance can be calculated from.

```
length(unique(x)) == 1
```

Comment: `length(unique(x))=1` ends up being about twice as fast, but `var` is terse which is nice.

Comment: YohanBadia, I have an array c(-5.532456e-09, 1.695298e-09), and get `John test: TRUE ; DWin test: TRUE ; zero-range test: TRUE ; variance test: FALSE` meaning all other test recognise that the values are identical in R. How can variance test be used in that context?

Comment: The 2 values in your array are not identical. Why would you want the test to return `TRUE` ? In the case of John's answer, you check whether the difference is above a certain threshold. In your case the difference between the 2 values is very low, which could lead to it beeing below the threshold you defined.

Comment: "Why not simply using the variance"? Because `var(x)` is `NA` for `x <- c("a", "b")`

Comment: Var will work in instances where the length of the vector in question change and the numeric that it equals is static, removes the need to reference more dynamic objects -- numeric only

Answer (score 43):

If they're all numeric values then if tol is your tolerance then...

```
all( abs(y - mean(y)) < tol )
```

is the solution to your problem.

**EDIT:**

After looking at this, and other answers, and benchmarking a few things the following comes out over twice as fast as the DWin answer.

```
abs(max(x) - min(x)) < tol
```

This is a bit surprisingly faster than `diff(range(x))` since `diff` shouldn't be much different than `-` and `abs` with two numbers. Requesting the range should optimize getting the minimum and maximum. Both `diff` and `range` are primitive functions. But the timing doesn't lie.

And, in addition, as @Waldi pointed out, `abs` is superfluous here.

Comment: Can you comment on the relative merits of subtracting off the mean compared to dividing by it?

Comment: It is computationally simpler.  Depending on the system, and how R is compiled and vectorized, it will be accomplished faster with less power consumption.  Also, when you divide by the mean your tested outcome is relative to 1 while with subtraction it's 0, which seems nicer to me.  Also, the tolerance has a more straightforward interpretation.

Comment: But it's not even so much that division is complex as the search and sort required to extract the range is much more computationally expensive than a simple subtraction.  I tested it and the above code is about 10x faster than the zero_range function Hadley (and yours is about the fastest correct answer here).  The compare function of Dirk's is brutally slow.  This is the fastest answer here.

Comment: Just saw Josh's timing comments in your answer Hadley...  I don't get any situations where zero_range is faster.  The discrepancy is between slightly faster (maybe 20%) to 10x always in favour if this answer.  It tried a number of methods.

Comment: Or simply : `max(x) - min(x)<tol` : `abs` isn't needed here as `max>=min`

Comment: @Waldi good point. Although, the parentheses around the subtraction would need to be retained.

Answer (score 33):

You can just check `all(v==v[1])`

Comment: This one is great bc it works with strings too! Thanks

Comment: This works unless you have `NA` in your vector:  `x <- c(1,1,NA); all(x == x[1])` returns `NA`, not `FALSE`. 

In such cases `length(unique(x)) == 1` works.

Answer (score 25):

```
> isTRUE(all.equal( max(y) ,min(y)) )
[1] TRUE
> isTRUE(all.equal( max(x) ,min(x)) )
[1] FALSE
```

Another along the same lines:

```
> diff(range(x)) < .Machine$double.eps ^ 0.5
[1] FALSE
> diff(range(y)) < .Machine$double.eps ^ 0.5
[1] TRUE
```

Comment: I don't think this works so well for very small numbers: `x <- seq(1, 10) / 1e10`

Comment: @Hadley: The OP asked for a solution that would allow specification of a tolerance, presumably because he didn't care about very small differences. all.equal can be used with other tolerances and the OP appears to understand this.

Comment: I didn't express myself very clearly - in my example there is a ten-fold relative difference between the largest and smallest numbers.  That's probably something you want to notice!  I think numerical tolerance needs to be calculated relative to the range of the data - I have not done this in the past and it has caused problems.

Comment: I don't think I misunderstood you in the slighest. I just thought the questioner was asking for a solution that would ignore a tenfold relative difference for numbers that are effectively zero. I heard him as asking for a solution that would ignore the difference between 1e-11 and 1e-13.

Comment: I try and give people what they need, not what they want ;)  But point taken.

Answer (score 16):

You can use `identical()` and `all.equal()` by comparing the first element to all others, effectively sweeping the comparison across:

```
R> compare <- function(v) all(sapply( as.list(v[-1]), 
+                         FUN=function(z) {identical(z, v[1])}))
R> compare(x)
[1] FALSE
R> compare(y)
[1] TRUE
R>
```

That way you can add any epsilon to `identical()` as needed.

Comment: Hideously inefficient though...  (on my computer it takes about 10 second for a million numbers)

Comment: No doubt. The OP was however questioning whether this could be done *at all*. Doing it well is a second step.  And you know where I stand with loops ... ;-)

Comment: That loops are awesome? ;)

Comment: What I like about this appoach is that it can be used with non numerical objects.

Comment: compare <- function(v) all(sapply( as.list(v[-1]), FUN=function(z) {isTRUE(all.equal(z, v[1]))}))

Comment: the isTRUE helps matters, because all.equal sometimes returns comparisons, not FALSE

Comment: If you want to work with non_numerical, why not just factor the object and count the number of levels? seems very fast on my machine

Answer (score 11):

Since I keep coming back to this question over and over, here's an `Rcpp` solution that will generally be much much faster than any of the `R` solutions if the answer is actually `FALSE` (because it will stop the moment it encounters a mismatch) and will have the same speed as the fastest R solution if the answer is `TRUE`. For example for the OP benchmark, `system.time` clocks in at exactly 0 using this function.

```
library(inline)
library(Rcpp)

fast_equal = cxxfunction(signature(x = 'numeric', y = 'numeric'), '
  NumericVector var(x);
  double precision = as<double>(y);

  for (int i = 0, size = var.size(); i < size; ++i) {
    if (var[i] - var[0] > precision || var[0] - var[i] > precision)
      return Rcpp::wrap(false);
  }

  return Rcpp::wrap(true);
', plugin = 'Rcpp')

fast_equal(c(1,2,3), 0.1)
#[1] FALSE
fast_equal(c(1,2,3), 2)
#[2] TRUE
```

Comment: This is nice & +1 for speed, but I'm not convinced that comparing all elements to the 1st element is quite right. A vector can pass this test, yet the difference between max(x) and min(x) be greater than precision. For example `fast_equal(c(2,1,3), 1.5)`

Comment: @dww What you're pointing out is that comparison is not transitive when you have precision issues - i.e. `a == b`, `b == c` does not necessarily imply `a == c` if you're doing floating point comparisons. You can either divide your precision by the number of elements to avoid this issue, or modify the algorithm to compute `min` and `max` and using that as a stopping condition.

Answer (score 10):

I wrote a function specifically for this, which can check not only elements in a vector, but also capable of checking if all elements in a list are **identical**. Of course it as well handle character vectors and all other types of vector well. It also has appropriate error handling.

```
all_identical <- function(x) {
  if (length(x) == 1L) {
    warning("'x' has a length of only 1")
    return(TRUE)
  } else if (length(x) == 0L) {
    warning("'x' has a length of 0")
    return(logical(0))
  } else {
    TF <- vapply(1:(length(x)-1),
                 function(n) identical(x[[n]], x[[n+1]]),
                 logical(1))
    if (all(TF)) TRUE else FALSE
  }
}
```

Now try some examples.

```
x <- c(1, 1, 1, NA, 1, 1, 1)
all_identical(x)       ## Return FALSE
all_identical(x[-4])   ## Return TRUE
y <- list(fac1 = factor(c("A", "B")),
          fac2 = factor(c("A", "B"), levels = c("B", "A"))
          )
all_identical(y)     ## Return FALSE as fac1 and fac2 have different level order
```

Answer (score 5):

You do not actually need to use min, mean, or max.
Based on John's answer:

```
all(abs(x - x[[1]]) < tolerance)
```

Answer (score 3):

Here an alternative using the min, max trick but for a data frame. In the example I am comparing columns but the margin parameter from `apply` can be changed to 1 for rows.

```
valid = sum(!apply(your_dataframe, 2, function(x) diff(c(min(x), max(x)))) == 0)
```

If `valid == 0` then all the elements are the same

Answer (score 2):

Another solution which uses the `data.table` package, compatible with strings and `NA` is `uniqueN(x) == 1`