# How can I replace values of 1 with values of .9999 in a column of data?

Tags: r

I'm have an issue with my analysis and would like to replace all of the 1's in a particular column with .9999, for example:

```
  SNP Pvalue
 rs11 0.6516
 rs12 0.3311
 rs13 1.0000
```

would become

```
  SNP Pvalue
rs11 0.6516
rs12 0.3311
rs13 0.9999
```

Thanks in advance for your replies.

Answer (score 4):

Assuming your data.frame is called mydf:

```
mydf$Pvalue[mydf$Pvalue==1] <- 0.9999
```

See `help('[<-')` or any number of introduction to R manuals such as this one:

http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-intro.pdf

Comment: There is a question of what is 1, as in `b=1-10^(-(1:20)); b[b==1]=0.9999; b`

Comment: Indeed.  @margaux note that if you care or are having trouble with floating point errors, replace the equality statement in brackets with something that has a slight tolerance.  For suggestions see here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4752275/test-for-equality-among-all-elements-of-a-single-vector