# Identify if 3 or more values are the same

Tags: r

I would like a way to tell if 3 or more lists have a length equal to another variable.  I can only find methods that work with 2 entries.

I have tried "==", all.equal and identical; neither of which work.  A small example is shown below, I would like to have some TEST fcn that returns TRUE to TEST(x,A,B,C) and FALSE to TEST(x,A,B,D) (or even just not TRUE will do).

A small example is shown below - apologies for the appalling formatting but was the only way I could get this to post

E.g.

```
x = 3

A = length(c(1,2,3))
B = length(c(4,5,7))
C = length(c(2,4,6))
D = length(c(1,2))


x==A
*[1] TRUE*

c==A==C
*Error: unexpected '==' in "c==A=="*

all.equal(x,A)
*[1] TRUE*

all.equal(x,D)
*[1] "Mean relative difference: 0.3333333"*

all.equal(x,A,D)
*[1] TRUE*

identical(x,B)
*[1] FALSE*

identical(x,D)
*[1] FALSE*

identical(A,B)
*[1] TRUE*

identical(A,D)
*[1] FALSE*
```

Comment: Might be of use to you: [test for equality among all elements of a single vector](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4752275/test-for-equality-among-all-elements-of-a-single-vector)

Comment: What if you did `sapply(list(A,B,C,D), "==", x)` Of course, that's just the same as `c(A,B,C,D) %in% x`

Comment: @RichardScriven - function your code snippet: `compare.all <- function(x,compare) { all(sapply(compare, "==", x)) }`  - then `compare.all(x, list(A,B,D) )` seems to work.

Comment: Thanks RichardScriven and thelatemail that gives me the result I was looking for.