# How to use lapply functions for logical operations across columns in a matrix in R?

Tags: r, boolean, apply, lapply

Is there a way to use apply in a matrix to compare items across columns with logical operators?

```
n.col <- 2
A <- matrix(sample(1:6, 1000*n.col, replace = TRUE), 1000 , ncol=n.col)
```

For each row I would like to check if the values of across cols are the same. For small values of `n.col` I just do:

```
A[ ,1] == A[ ,2]
```

But this gets pretty unwieldy for large `n.cols`. I could do something ugly with a loop but I would love to know if there is some way to use `apply/lapply` for this.

Comment: Did you try something like: `lapply(seq(1,n.col,2), function(n) A[,n] == A[,n+1])`

Comment: Cool workaround, but closer to what I have already with my for loop (a additional comparison is need after the lapply). Thanks for the suggestion anyway!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `apply` for rows/columns of a matrix:

```
cols.equal <- apply(A, 1, function(x) length(unique(x)) == 1)
```

**Edit:**
If your application involves floating point numbers, `length(unique(x))` won't really work because numbers will be "almost" the same, yet the number of unique elements will be larger than one. If that's the case, you can replace the function inside `apply` with 
the answer here:
[Test for equality among all elements of a single vector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4752275/test-for-equality-among-all-elements-of-a-single-vector)