# Iterating name of a field with dplyr::summarise function

Tags: r, dataframe, loops

first time for me here, I'll try to explain you my problem as clearly as possible.
I'm working on erosion data contained in farms in the form of pixels (e.g. 1 farm = 10 pixels so 10 lines in my df), for this I have 4 df in a list, and I would like to calculate for each farm the mean of erosion. I thought about a loop on the name of erosion field but my problem is that my df don't have the exact name (either ERO13 or ERO17). I don't want to work the position of the field because it could change between the df, only with the name which is variable.

**Here's a example :**

```
df1 <- data.frame(ID = c(1,1,2), ERO13 = c(2,4,6))
df2 <- data.frame(ID = c(4,4,6), ERO17 = c(4,5,12))
lst_df <- list(df1,df2)
for (df in lst_df){
  cur_df <- df
  cur_df <- cur_df %>% 
    group_by(ID) %>% 
    summarise(current_name_of_erosion_field = mean(current_name_of_erosion_field))
}
```

I tried with

```
for (df in lst_df){
  cur_df <- df
  cur_camp <- names(cur_df)[2]
  cur_df <- cur_df %>% 
    group_by(ID) %>% 
    summarise(cur_camp = mean(cur_camp))
}
```

but first doesn't work because it's a string character and not a variable containing the string character and it works with the position.

**How can I build the current_name_of_erosion_field here ?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We may convert it to `sym`bol and evaluate (`!!`) or may pass the string  `across`.  Also, as we are using a `for` loop, make sure to create a `list` to store the output.  Also, to assign from an object created, use `:=` with `!!`

```
out <- vector('list', length(lst_df))
for (i in seq_along(lst_df)){
  cur_df <- lst_df[[i]]
  cur_camp <- names(cur_df)[2]
  cur_df <- cur_df %>% 
    group_by(ID) %>% 
    summarise(!!cur_camp := mean(!! sym(cur_camp)))
  out[[i]] <- cur_df
}
```

-output

```
> out
[[1]]
# A tibble: 2 × 2
     ID ERO13
  <dbl> <dbl>
1     1     3
2     2     6

[[2]]
# A tibble: 2 × 2
     ID ERO17
  <dbl> <dbl>
1     4   4.5
2     6  12
```

---

Or may use `across`

```
out <- vector('list', length(lst_df))
for (i in seq_along(lst_df)){
  cur_df <- lst_df[[i]]
  cur_camp <- names(cur_df)[2]
  cur_df <- cur_df %>% 
    group_by(ID) %>% 
    summarise(across(all_of(cur_camp), mean))
  out[[i]] <- cur_df
}
```

-output

```
> out
[[1]]
# A tibble: 2 × 2
     ID ERO13
  <dbl> <dbl>
1     1     3
2     2     6

[[2]]
# A tibble: 2 × 2
     ID ERO17
  <dbl> <dbl>
1     4   4.5
2     6  12
```

Comment: ,akrun Master could you please check here <https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70707472/how-to-left-rows-with-the-same-values-in-columns-using-dplyr-package-in-r/70708360?noredirect=1#comment125000992_70708360> if `if_all` is possible?

Comment: @TarJae i guess `test %>% filter(if_all(var2:var3, ~ . == var1))` should work based on the example I tested there

Comment: thks you a lot @akrun, I chose the across solution which seems to be the clearest for me. Can you explain a bit about this syntax which is totally new for me : summarise(!!cur_camp := mean(!! sym(cur_camp))) ; you start with a string character to turn it into the name of variable (symbol), don't you ?

Comment: @Béranger the `=` doesn't evaluate the object on the lhs, thus if you do `cur_camp = mean(`, the column name will be `cur_camp`, whereas the assignment operator in tidyverse (`:=`) does allow for evaluation (`!!`) of object to return the value of it.  Similarly on the rhs, we need to get the value of the column name string stored in cur_camp.  Thus, convert to `sym`bol and evaluate (`!!`)

Answer (score 0):

A slightly different approach would be to `bind` the dataframes and use `pivot_longer` to separate the erosion name from the erosion value. Then you can take the mean of the values without having to specify the name.

```r
library(tidyverse)

df1 <- data.frame(ID = c(1,1,2), ERO13 = c(2,4,6))
df2 <- data.frame(ID = c(4,4,6), ERO17 = c(4,5,12))

bind_rows(df1, df2) %>%
  pivot_longer(starts_with('ERO'), 
               names_to = 'ERO',
               values_drop_na = TRUE) %>%
  group_by(ID, ERO) %>%
  summarize(value = mean(value))
#> `summarise()` has grouped output by 'ID'. You can override using the `.groups` argument.
#> # A tibble: 4 x 3
#> # Groups:   ID [4]
#>      ID ERO   value
#>   <dbl> <chr> <dbl>
#> 1     1 ERO13   3  
#> 2     2 ERO13   6  
#> 3     4 ERO17   4.5
#> 4     6 ERO17  12
```

<sup>Created on 2022-01-14 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>