# nullify columns where all values are the same

Tags: r, apply

I've got a big matrix in R represented by the following one:

```
A     B    C
0.01  0.9  0.1
0.02  0.7  0.1
0.9   0.8  0.1
0.003 0.08 0.1
```

I want to nullify all the columns that have all equal values like column C so that it becomes:

```
A     B    C
0.01  0.9  NA
0.02  0.7  NA
0.9   0.8  NA
0.003 0.08 NA
```

How to do it?

Comment: why do you want to do this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
a <- matrix(c(0.01, 0.02, 0.09, 0.003, 0.9, 0.7, 0.8, 0.08, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1), 4, 3)
```

Below should work whether `a` is numeric or otherwise

```
a[, apply(a, 2, function(x) length(unique(x))== 1)] <- NA
```

If the values of `a` are arrived by some computation then  [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4752275/test-for-equality-among-all-elements-of-a-single-vector) thread may be useful.

Answer (score 2):

If your matrix is called `m1`, then the column with all the same values will have zero variance, so we can go with that, i.e.

```
m1[,apply(m1, 2, var) == 0] <- NA
```

Comment: should be faster to detect `length(unique(x)) == 1L`

Comment: `length(unique(x)) == 1L` suggestion will also take care of non numeric matrix whereas `var` will work only for numbers

Answer (score 0):

Try this vectorized (say `m` is your matrix):

```
m[,(colSums(m)/m[1,])==nrow(m)] <- NA
```

Comment: but it will wrong if first row equal column mean for any column but other rows are different