# Is there an efficient way to check whether an R character vector contains the same elements?

Tags: r, vector

Let's say I have an R vector of type `character`:

```
vector1 = c("dog", "cat", "fish")
vector2 = c("fish", "fish", "fish")
```

The first vector `vector1` contains three distinct elements: dog, cat, fish

However, `vector2` contains all the same elements.

I'm looking for an efficient way to check this property in an R vector, preferably using base R.

My idea would be to use the following:

Check `length(unique(vector1))==1`. If `TRUE`, then there's only 1 element. If `FALSE`, there are many.

Comment: What is wrong with the solution that you give with length and unique?

Comment: You provide a solution in your question, but you haven't explained how or why that solution isn't "efficient" enough for you.

Comment: @G5W You're right. This would probably be the most efficient way in base R. I recommend this question be deleted

Comment: @ShanZhengYang actually `length(unique()) == 1` is quite inefficient compared to `all()`

Comment: `all(x==x[1])` seems to be faster than `length(unique(x))==1`. How fast does it have to be?

Comment: If your vectors are huge, uniqueN or anyDuplicated from package data.table might be of interest.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Alternatively, you can use `all`.

```
> all(vector1 == vector1[1])
[1] FALSE
> all(vector2 == vector2[1])
[1] TRUE
```

Comment: Actually I got quicker results with my solution with `microbenchmark` : `a <- rep("fish",5000000); b <- c(a[1:4999999], "cat"); microbenchmark(all(a == a[1]), all(a[-1] == a[1]), all(b == b[1]), all(b[-1] == b[1]))`.

Comment: @snoram this will make it less efficient (I mean, slower) in most cases

Comment: Interesting! My bad!

Answer (score 6):

If you're concerned with speed is looks like either @AshOfFire's `all(vec == vec[1])` or `uniqueN(vec) == 1` is the best. `all(...)` has better performance when the elements are different, but worse when they're the same. There are other posts on this topic here as well: [Test for equality among all elements of a single vector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4752275/test-for-equality-among-all-elements-of-a-single-vector)

Since you explicitly ask about speed, I don't know if this should be flagged as a dupe or not. Doing some quick microbenchmarking you can see the relative speeds:

```
library(data.table)
benchmark_vec <- function(vec){
  microbenchmark::microbenchmark(length(unique(vec)) == 1,
                                 all(vec == vec[1]),
                                 isTRUE(max(vec) == min(vec)),
                                 uniqueN(vec)==1,
                                 unit = "relative")
}
```

It looks like your best bet might be to use `uniqueN(vec) == 1` since `isTRUE(max(vec) == min(vec))` is quite slow when the elements are not the same.

**Vector of same elements:**

```
benchmark_vec(rep("a", 1e4))
#Unit: relative
#                         expr      min       lq     mean   median        uq      max neval
#     length(unique(vec)) == 1 6.059888 8.980080 8.807812 9.057240 10.131907 6.538035   100
#           all(vec == vec[1]) 2.039980 2.117614 2.517966 2.769089  2.820726 2.147200   100
# isTRUE(max(vec) == min(vec)) 1.000000 1.000000 1.000000 1.000000  1.000000 1.000000   100
#            uniqueN(vec) == 1 1.679993 1.794075 2.148665 2.442206  2.547134 1.385782   100

benchmark_vec(rep("a", 1e5))
#Unit: relative
#                         expr      min       lq     mean   median       uq       max neval
#     length(unique(vec)) == 1 5.732161 6.898531 7.935981 7.098417 6.776363 52.733981   100
#           all(vec == vec[1]) 2.084232 2.416316 2.366826 2.482896 2.454888  2.025258   100
# isTRUE(max(vec) == min(vec)) 1.000000 1.000000 1.000000 1.000000 1.000000  1.000000   100
#            uniqueN(vec) == 1 1.254857 1.653767 1.632287 1.707769 1.755275  1.401932   100

benchmark_vec(rep("a", 1e6))
#Unit: relative
#                         expr      min       lq     mean   median       uq      max neval
#     length(unique(vec)) == 1 5.993300 6.057139 6.478008 6.083278 6.104486 9.124542   100
#           all(vec == vec[1]) 2.249211 2.182959 2.261631 2.182345 2.224141 6.421657   100
# isTRUE(max(vec) == min(vec)) 1.000000 1.000000 1.000000 1.000000 1.000000 1.000000   100
#            uniqueN(vec) == 1 1.325453 1.451214 1.869176 1.457588 1.470810 6.657961   100
```

**Vector of different elements:**

```
benchmark_vec(sample(LETTERS, 1e4, replace = TRUE))
#Unit: relative
#                         expr       min        lq      mean    median        uq  #     max neval
#     length(unique(vec)) == 1  2.989151  2.999928  3.233178  3.031249  3.260122  4.471498   100
#           all(vec == vec[1])  1.000000  1.000000  1.000000  1.000000  1.000000  1.000000   100
# isTRUE(max(vec) == min(vec)) 92.619106 91.765377 89.899963 92.227913 93.951104 64.507502   100
#            uniqueN(vec) == 1  1.478271  1.494703  1.608562  1.531235  1.637707  2.528502   100

benchmark_vec(sample(LETTERS, 1e5, replace = TRUE))
#Unit: relative
#                         expr       min        lq      mean    median        uq       max neval
#     length(unique(vec)) == 1  3.142858  3.010220  2.945582  2.887597  2.925129  4.482119   100
#           all(vec == vec[1])  1.000000  1.000000  1.000000  1.000000  1.000000  1.000000   100
# isTRUE(max(vec) == min(vec)) 97.273487 79.818135 73.850769 75.442748 71.441439 41.772795   100
#            uniqueN(vec) == 1  1.280180  1.431999  2.009661  1.431815  1.447287 32.446761   100

benchmark_vec(sample(LETTERS, 1e6, replace = TRUE))
#Unit: relative
#                         expr       min        lq      mean    median        uq       max neval
#     length(unique(vec)) == 1  3.228670  2.898367  2.799075  2.941651  2.914313  1.360938   100
#           all(vec == vec[1])  1.000000  1.000000  1.000000  1.000000  1.000000  1.000000   100
# isTRUE(max(vec) == min(vec)) 92.506220 79.923456 67.347683 78.362151 75.028194 13.611664   100
#            uniqueN(vec) == 1  2.263843  2.031869  1.861165  2.058220  2.051759  1.129074   100
```

Comment: `isTRUE(max(x)==min(x))` is such a nice idea ... and seems to work on character vectors as well

Comment: Actually @AshOfFire has  `all(vec == vec[1])` not `all(vec[-1] == vec[1])`. Anyway it seems further tests have revealed the message that trying to beat `data.table` is futile.

Comment: @snoram aaannnddd I was wrong! Looks like AshOfFire's is the fastest on my machine for different elements

Comment: Thanks Mike! This is a great answer, as it has the benchmarks. However, as @AshOfFire did provide the method and could use more reputation points, I'll give him/her the answer.

Answer (score 2):

Inspired by both AshofFire and Mike:

```
!any(vec < vec[1])
```