# R, problems using a for cycle inside if else

Tags: r, for-loop, if-statement

I am trying to check if all the elements inside a vector are the same. I am using this code:

```
if( isTRUE(for(i in 1:length(x)){x[1]==x[i]})){print(x[1])} else{print("several")
```

Now suppose

```
x <- c(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0)
```

Here, the code should return "0" and if

```
x <- c(0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0)
```

it should return "several". In both cases I get "several", any idea why is not working as desired? 
Thank u in advance.

Comment: Do you need `any(x != 0)`

Comment: Where does `testpos[1]` come from?  Also check out this question for better alternatives: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4752275/test-for-equality-among-all-elements-of-a-single-vector. A "for" loop in R doesn't return any values.

Comment: srry editing testpos should be x

Answer (score 2, accepted):

there is a simpler way:

```
if (length(unique(x)) == 1) {
  print(x[1])
} else {
  print("several")
}
```

If you want to compare all components of `x` with the first component you should use `all` instead of a for loop:

```
if (all(x == x[1])) {
  print(x[1])
} else {
  print("several")
}
```

The result of both approaches is the same.

Comment: thank you very much! it works perfectly, really really thank you