# R - Compare vector of objects using Reduce

Tags: r, object, compare, reduce

I am trying to compare vector a of objects using Reduce

- **all.equal does not work**
- == works for numericals but will not be sufficient for objects.

I would prefer a solution that does not use existing packages but R core functions only

Example (**Simplified** to use **numeric vectors** instead of objects):

```
test <- c(1,1,1,1,1)

Reduce("==",test)

[1] TRUE
```

I do not understand **why == works while all.equal does not**

```
Reduce(all.equal,test)

[1] "Modes: character, numeric"              
[2] "Lengths: 3, 1"                          
[3] "target is character, current is numeric"
```

Final remark:

This is **not a duplicate**. I am interested in a solution that compares **objects not numeric values**

Comparison of the elements of a vector of numeric values: See existing solution on stackoverflow
[Test for equality among all elements of a single numeric vector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4752275/test-for-equality-among-all-elements-of-a-single-numeric-vector)

Comment: The problem with  `==` is that `1 == TRUE` evals as `TRUE`, but `all.equal(1, TRUE)` doesn't. If you run `Reduce(all.equal, test)` firstly it'll run all.equal(1, 1), which is TRUE; secondly, all.equal(1, TRUE), which results in a character, and so on. Have a look at this code for more details: 
`Reduce(all.equal, test, accumulate = TRUE)`.

Comment: Your example of `c(1,1,1)` just works because of `1 == TRUE`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try `identical` in `sapply` and compare each with the first element.

```
x <- list(list(1), list(1))
all(sapply(x[-1], identical, x[[1]]))
#[1] TRUE

x <- list(list(1), list(2))
all(sapply(x[-1], identical, x[[1]]))
#[1] FALSE
```

Comment: This solution ist more than 20 times faster than danloos solution for lists of large objects. Therefore this is the accepted answer

Answer (score 0):

Here is a function returning TRUE if all pairwise comparisons of the elements inside a list were identical:

```r
all_pairs_equal <- function(elements) {
    all(mapply(function(x, y) identical(elements[x], elements[y]), 1, seq(1, length(elements))))
}

all_pairs_equal(list(iris, iris, iris))
#> [1] TRUE
all_pairs_equal(list(1, 1, 1))
#> [1] TRUE
all_pairs_equal(list(iris, iris, 2))
#> [1] FALSE
```

<sup>Created on 2021-10-05 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: I think there is no need to compare each with each other. If all are equal it must be enough to test of all are equal to the first.

Comment: Thats true, I revised my answer

Comment: Now its not much difference to `all(sapply(x, identical, x[[1]]))`

Comment: Yes, but we can start at the second element because the reference element is always identical to itself

Comment: Yes but then it needs to be tested if there is a second element for the case there is only one element...

Comment: This solution has a good coding style and works as far as I can test it. Therefore upvote. Faster solution of GKi gets the accepted answer