# How to improve the speed of `length(unique(x)) == n`?

Tags: r

In a custom function, I want to run an `if` condition if my vector only has one unique value. I can use `length(unique(x)) == 1`. However, I think that this could be more efficient: instead of getting all the unique values in the vector and then count them, I could just stop after having found one value that is different from the first one:

```r
# Should be TRUE
test <- rep(1, 1e7)

bench::mark(
  length(unique(test)) == 1,
  all(test == test[1])
)
#> Warning: Some expressions had a GC in every iteration; so filtering is disabled.
#> # A tibble: 2 × 6
#>   expression                     min   median `itr/sec` mem_alloc `gc/sec`
#>   <bch:expr>                <bch:tm> <bch:tm>     <dbl> <bch:byt>    <dbl>
#> 1 length(unique(test)) == 1  154.1ms  158.6ms      6.31   166.1MB     6.31
#> 2 all(test == test[1])        38.1ms   49.2ms     19.6     38.1MB     3.92

# Should be FALSE
test2 <- rep(c(1, 2), 1e7)

bench::mark(
  length(unique(test2)) == 1,
  all(test2 == test2[1])
)
#> Warning: Some expressions had a GC in every iteration; so filtering is disabled.
#> # A tibble: 2 × 6
#>   expression                      min   median `itr/sec` mem_alloc `gc/sec`
#>   <bch:expr>                 <bch:tm> <bch:tm>     <dbl> <bch:byt>    <dbl>
#> 1 length(unique(test2)) == 1  341.2ms  386.1ms      2.59   332.3MB     2.59
#> 2 all(test2 == test2[1])       59.5ms   81.1ms     11.5     76.3MB     1.92
```

It is indeed more efficient.

Now, suppose that I want to replace `length(unique(x)) == 2`. I could probably do something similar to stop as soon as I find 3 different values but I don't see how can I generalize this to replace `length(unique(x)) == n` where `n` can be any positive integer.

**Is there an efficient and general way to do this?**

(I'm looking for a solution in base R, and if you can improve the benchmark for `n = 1`, feel free to suggest).

Comment: With `data.table` `uniqueN` should be better than length(unique` i.e. `uniqueN(test) == 1`

Comment: If `test` is an integer valued vector, you could go with `tabulate`, i.e. `n <- 1`, `tab <- tabulate(test)` and `length(tab) == 1 & tab[n] > 0`. But I'm unsure if this speeds things up.

Comment: @akrun Interestingly, with `data.table 1.14.5`, `uniqueN` is faster than `length(unique())` in the first example but is slower in the second one. In both cases the `all()` alternative is faster

Comment: @bretauv Please note the there is [an open issue on the speed of `uniqueN`](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/3739). You may check `collapse::fndistinct`. Not `base` though ;) Cheers

Comment: Do you want to stop on  **exactly** N distinct values, or  any case  of 1 : N distinct values?

Comment: @CarlWitthoft exactly N distinct values

Answer (score 1):

For `n = 1`, [a simple Rcpp solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17754949/9463489) may be fastest.

For variable values of `n`, take advantage of the `nmax` argument in `duplicated`. It isn't much slower than the `all(test == test[1])` solution for `n = 1`.

```
f <- function(x, n = 1L) {
  if (n == 1L) {
    all(x == x[1])
  } else {
    try({
      out <- FALSE
      out <- sum(!duplicated(x, nmax = max(n - 1L, 2L))) == n
    },
    silent = TRUE)
    out
  }
}
```

If you're willing to use the `data.table` package, `uniqueN` is even faster.

```
library(data.table)

test1 <- integer(1e7)
test2 <- replace(test1, sample(length(test1), 1), 1L)
test3 <- replace(test1, sample(length(test1), 2), 1:2)
test4 <- replace(test1, sample(length(test1), 3), 1:3)

microbenchmark::microbenchmark(test11 = f(test1),
                               test11u = uniqueN(test1) == 1L,
                               test21 = !(f(test2)),
                               test21u = !(uniqueN(test2) == 1L),
                               test12 = !(f(test1, 2L)),
                               test12u = !(uniqueN(test1) == 2L),
                               test22 = f(test2, 2L),
                               test22u = uniqueN(test2) == 2L,
                               test32 = !(f(test3, 2L)),
                               test32u = !(uniqueN(test3) == 2L),
                               test33 = f(test3, 3L),
                               test33u = uniqueN(test3) == 3L,
                               test42 = !(f(test4, 2L)),
                               test42u = !(uniqueN(test4) == 2L),
                               times = 10L,
                               check = "identical"
)
#> Unit: milliseconds
#>     expr     min      lq     mean   median      uq     max neval
#>   test11 19.7039 21.0140 24.53535 25.34470 28.1465 29.2522    10
#>  test11u  8.4288  8.4487 11.75907  9.01450 15.7135 17.6662    10
#>   test21 15.6819 16.3501 19.96841 20.67490 23.4805 24.5174    10
#>  test21u 22.0334 22.9321 24.48876 23.89990 24.9918 30.1270    10
#>   test12 56.7494 58.1082 61.04971 59.28220 63.2788 70.6369    10
#>  test12u  8.2359  8.2733 11.00223  8.80760 13.6347 20.3073    10
#>   test22 56.0069 58.3666 60.97008 59.13500 65.1769 66.3205    10
#>  test22u 23.6497 24.5786 27.64053 27.53345 29.6208 33.7244    10
#>   test32 56.1626 62.4090 68.80590 63.91255 68.2029 98.7681    10
#>  test32u 22.2644 22.5803 26.76258 23.41385 32.5339 33.6664    10
#>   test33 59.1070 62.5212 63.17074 63.30035 64.3413 66.1363    10
#>  test33u 22.4709 22.7972 25.10889 23.01645 28.1002 30.9884    10
#>   test42 38.3762 44.5015 44.65828 44.81795 46.0175 51.4117    10
#>  test42u 22.4919 23.0305 24.61079 23.68880 24.0825 29.8777    10
```

Comment: `uniqueN` has beat various hacks I've tried so far.

Answer (score 0):

To answer the second bit:  I suspect  `if(mean(x) == x[1])` will be faster yet, with the usual warning (which applies to your code snippets as well) about comparing floats.

**EDIT**   as a comment points out,  `mean( x,x-1,x+1) == x`  so maybe a better "quick" method would be  `sd(x) == 0`

Another thing to check out might be `length(rle(sort(x)$values)`  {disclaimer: I love `rle` for everything} .

[and a demerit for me posting this before running `microbenchmark` on samples]

Comment: Indeed the `mean()` one is faster, but the `length(rle())` is much slower

Comment: Note that the `mean()` solution doesn't work in some cases: with `x <- c(7, 6, 8)`, the mean is 7 so it returns TRUE but there are 3 distinct values

Comment: @bretauv  guess it'll have to be   `mean(x)==x[1] && sd(x) == 0`   :-)